# random EntityValidationErrors (The field is required)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been trying to update an Entity using the following code:

```
var db = new MyContext();

var data = db.Tableau.Find(Id);

if (data != null)
{
    data.Name = model.Name;
    data.EmbedCode = model.EmbedCode;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is that my Tableaus table has a Parent field (FK not null to a DataTree table). Sometimes when I save the changes to this edited record, I get an error saying that "The Parent field is required". But I am not editing the Parent field. The parent field should be intact and existent, since I am only altering the Name and EmbedCode fields.

How to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention asp.net and mvc here, are you serializing this data and then making the changes on the return (or post back)?  If so this is likely where your problem is.  The code you have posted should work just fine, but I suspect this is not what the real code looks like.

Comment: I have a ModelView. This data is POSTed to the Edit controller. I fetch the Tableu from the Id that is passed on the URL and get the Name and EmbedCode from the ModelView of the Edit page. It should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are allowing `null` values in `ParentId` column in your `Tableaus` table, but in your `Tableau` entity you have `ParentId` as non-nullable property( which it means the relationship is required), and when you load a `Tableau` instance from your DB, EF expects that you set that property too. Try changing that property to nullable:

```
public int? ParentId {get;set;}
```

If you configure your relationship using Fluent Api it would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tableau>()
            .HasOptional(t=>t.Parent)
            .WithMany(dt=>dt.Tablous)// if you don't have a collection nav. property in your DataTree entity, you can call this method without parameter
            .HasForeignKey(t=>t.ParentId);
```

### Update 1

If you want `ParentId` property as `Required` in your `Tableau` entity, you need to make sure that you have  a valid value in that column in your DB per each row. With a "valid value" I mean it should be different of the default value and it should exist as PK in your `DataTree` table.

### Update 2:

One way to load a related entity as part of your query is using `Include` extension method:

```
var data = db.Tableau.Include(t=>t.Parent).FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Id==Id);
```

Comment: but I want to ensure that every `Tableau` have a `Parent`, that is why I made my `Tableau` model with a `[Required]` field on`Parent`, making it nullable: false.

What I can't understand is why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Every record of Tableau has a Parent on the database. When I use First(Id) to get the data, it should have the Parent field set correctly.

Comment: And with the `Tablaou` instance that you modify, did you check if EF loads `ParentId` properly? You shouldn't have issues loading scalar properties, if you have a value there, it should be loaded

Comment: Some additional info: 
whenever I am debugging the code, it works perfectly. If I stop the code somewhere to check the variables, the data variable is perfect and it saves perfectly.
It seems like the Parent is taking too long to load and when I save it didn't load everything yet. The Parent also has a Parent, in a Data Tree structure. Maybe that is why it is crashing, because I guess it is not loading everything before I save the changes.

Is there a way to say to EF: okay, don't get me the Parent, only ParentId (because then I treat the ParentId as a int, not as an entity)

Comment: @VitorSubs that's odd, is the first time that I hear something like that, scalar properties should be loaded instantaneously when you load your entity. Anyways, try loading your `Tablaou` instance using `FistOrDefault` method instead `Find`

Comment: It made no difference. I found an ugly workaround: I disable lazyloading and force loading of the Parent model manually. It is working perfectly, although I don't like this solution...

Comment: ohh, now that you mention that, is your `Parent` navigation property is not `virtual`?, because it is not, you should change it to virtual, it's a requirement of lazy loading

Comment: It is virtual! But the Parent is of DataTree kind. And the DataTree has a DataTree parent as well. It is recursive. I guess this recursiveness of loading parents is making this "bug" happen. With my workaround I ensure only the first parent is loaded. It works now.